# Lie bracket on $\Gamma(TM\oplus (M\times \mathfrak{g}))$?

Tags: lie-algebras, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $(\mathfrak{g}, [\cdot, \cdot])$ be a $\mathbb R$-Lie algebra. How can I introduce a Lie bracket on $\Gamma(TM\oplus (M\times \mathfrak{g}))$?

Above $TM\oplus (M\times \mathfrak{g})$ is the Whitney sum of the tangent bundle of $M$ and the trivial bundle $M\times \mathfrak{g}$.

I have some considerations for now: It is easy to see the map $\sigma:C^\infty(M)\otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \Gamma(M\times \mathfrak{g})$, $f\otimes v\longmapsto \sigma_{f, v}$ where $$\sigma_{f, v}(p)=(p, f(p)v),$$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb R$-spaces. This way $$\Gamma(TM\oplus (M\times \mathfrak{g}))\simeq \Gamma(TM)\oplus (C^\infty(M)\otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathfrak{g}),$$ as $\mathbb R$-spaces. So, the attempt would be something like $$[(X, f\otimes u), (Y, g\otimes v)]=([X, Y], (X(g)-Y(f))\otimes [u, v]).$$ But it is not working because: $$\begin{align*}
\displaystyle [(Y, g\otimes v), (X, f\otimes u)]&= ([Y, X], (Y(f)-X(g))\otimes [v, u])\\
&=(-[X, Y], -(X(g)-Y(f))\otimes (-[u, v]))\\
&=(-[X, Y], (X(g)-Y(f))\otimes [u, v]).
\end{align*}$$ so it is not anti-symmetric. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are there any requirements at all on this Lie bracket you want? Because there's always the zero bracket... What are you trying to do? (Let me just mention that if $A$ is commutative and $\mathfrak{g}$ is Lie, then there's a Lie bracket on $A \otimes \mathfrak{g}$ given by $[a \otimes x, b \otimes y] = ab \otimes [x,y]$. Let $A = C^\infty(M)$. This then gives a Lie bracket $[(X,f \otimes x), (Y, g \otimes y)] = ([X,Y], fg \otimes [x,y])$. Does this work for you?)

Comment: Indeed, I want certain compatibility. I'd like to introduce a bracket on $TM\oplus (M\times \mathfrak{g})$ such that it becames a lie algebroid on $M$. In general, the compatibility is: Given a vector bundle $A\longrightarrow M$ and a morphism $\rho:A\longrightarrow TM$ then for every $\alpha, \beta\in \Gamma(A)$ and every $f\in C^\infty(M)$, $$[\alpha, f\cdot \beta]=f\cdot [\alpha, \beta]+\mathcal{L}_{\rho_*(\alpha)}(f)\cdot \beta$$ where $\rho_*$ is the induced map on sections. For me, $A=TM\oplus (M\times \mathfrak{g})$ and $\rho=\textrm{pr}_2|_{A}$.

Comment: I think the conceptual way to do this is to identify the space of sections you are looking at with the space of those vector fields on $M\times G$, which are invariant under the $G$-action defined by multiplication from the right. Then this is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak X(M\times G)$ so you can restrict the Lie bracket.